# How to fit a negative binomial distribution in R while incorporating censoring

Tags: r

I need to fit `Y_ij ~ NegBin(m_ij,k)`, hence a negative binomial distribution to a count. However, the data I have observed are censored, I know the value of `y_ij`, but it could be more than that value. Writting down the loglikelihood going with this problem is:

```
ll = \sum_{i=1}^n w_i (c_i log(P(Y_ij=y_ij|X_ij)) + (1- c_i) log(1- \sum_{k=1}^32 P(Y_ij = k|X_ij)))
```

Where `X_ij` represent the design matrix (with the covariates of interest), `w_i` is the weight for each observation, `y_ij` is the response variable and `P(Y_ij=y_ij|Xij)` is the negative binomial distribution where the `m_ij=exp(X_ij \beta)` and `\alpha` is the overdispersion parameter.

Does someone knows if there exist a build-in code in R that could be used to obtain this?

Comment: Your question is fairly statistical so you could try asking it at the new stats exchange site (http://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Check this paper out: [Regression Models for Count Data in R](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pscl/vignettes/countreg.pdf&pli=1)